# Not sure why my AJAX call doesn't populate data in webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, webforms

When the page is ready, I want it to call the function BindGridView that will populate the data in GridView. I have no clue why it won't step into the "Success" part in Ajax. I'm doing something similar in another ajax call and it works fine. I've followed the tutorial pretty much exactly. I am getting a 500 (Internal Server Error).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindDummyItem();
        }

        public void BindDummyItem()
        {
            DataTable dtGetData = new DataTable();
            dtGetData.Columns.Add("ID");
            dtGetData.Columns.Add("ServerName");;
            dtGetData.Columns.Add("Command");
            dtGetData.Columns.Add("CreateDate");
            dtGetData.Rows.Add();

            GridView1.DataSource = dtGetData;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

[WebMethod]
        public static sObj[] test()
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["asdasd"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            List<s> sl = new List<s>();
            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("stredP", con);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StarteDate", "2017-07-24 19:20:00"));
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", "2017-07-24 19:21:00"));

                da.Fill(dataTable);

                foreach (DataRow dtRow in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    sObj DataObj = new sObj();
                    DataObj.ID = Convert.ToInt64(dtRow["ID"]);
                    DataObj.ServerName = dtRow["ServerName"].ToString();
                    DataObj.Command = dtRow["Command"].ToString();
                    DataObj.CreateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dtRow["CreateDate"]);
                    sl.Add(DataObj);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return sl.ToArray();
        }
```

Code in .aspx

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        BindGridView();
    });

    function BindGridView() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ProjectName.aspx/test",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("dfgdgdfgdfg");
                $("#GridView1").empty();

                if (data.d.length > 0) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                        $("#GridView1").append("<tr><td>" + 
                        data.d[i].ID + "</td> <td>" +
                        data.d[i].ServerName + "</td> <td>" +
                        data.d[i].Command + "</td></tr>" +
                        data.d[i].CreateDate + "</td></tr>");
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                //alert("Error login");

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the error on the backend, perhaps in your catch block?

Comment: @TimSmojver I found out that the string I'm trying to serialize is bigger than what it can handle (100kbs).

Comment: @jss what line of code is this being thrown?

Comment: @TimSmojver I'm printing out error msg in  error: function (result) {}. I tried the same code with less data and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Setting this in Web.Config will increase the length :

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
          <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

founded on this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength(v=vs.110).aspx